# Запустить Perl-скрипт на Windows

Tags: active-perl, perl

Добрый Вечер! как можно запустить данный [скрипт](https://github.com/kud/jpegrescan) на Windows?

Вроде все необходимые компоненты есть, но у меня никак не выходит заставить его работать, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а [jpegtrans](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/) установлен и доступен?

Comment: Какие ошибки выдаёт?

Comment: jpegtran установлен и доступен.
никаких ошибок не выдает.

Answer (score 1):

Просто взять и запустить по виндой не получится, так как скрипт требует linux систему и jpegtran. Если хотите под виндой, то есть бинарник jpegtran для винды на офф сайте, но скрипт придётся самому немного допилить под это дело.

Comment: Мне надо именно через винду запустить, скажите, а что надо изменить в скрипте?

Comment: Ну при беглом осмотре вот что выходит:
*заменить вызов jpegtran через open на какой нить `$cmd`;
*выкинуть все перенаправления потоков вроде STDERR, ибо не помню такого я в винде.

как вариант можно ещё попробовать поставить cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ARGV==2 or die "usage: jpegrescan in.jpg out.jpg
```

Если переданных аргументов командной строки не 2, то умри. А перед смертью напиши:

> для использования скрипта надо передавать 2 аргумента: входящее изображение и исходящее

Для работы нужен либо интерпретатор перла, либо компилятор(который даст вам сразу скомпилированный код для конкретной платформы), либо виртуальная машина(такая как *Parrot*, если хотите перл использовать с другим языком)

PS еще доступны ключи скрипта, приводится их список.

Comment: Ну во первых у перла нет компилятора, во вторых Parrot это дохлый проект, который вообщем то с perl ничего общего не имеет(perl 6 на нём это полная глупость).